# Jade and jQuery together

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

Folks,
  How would I implement jQuery styles on a form that I generate using Jade?  What I am trying to do is to `prettify` forms and make them clickable.  I am terrible at UI.  period.

How would I implement this selectable method on a form? http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

`pendingArray` is an Array of JSON objects coming from `Express`.  Just need to draw it and make it clickable.  Upon a click, I would like a popup window open that I can POST to my api with...   Being a backend programmer, this UI stuff is completely over my head as I never spend any time in this void.

page.jade:

```
include mainNavMenu

body
    h1= title
    p#container Welcome to #{title}
    p#message (to be filled in)
    script
        alert('hello world');
        $("#message").html("message set through jquery")

block Content

if (pendingArray)
    - each val, key in pendingArray
        <h1>#{val}</h1>
```

Comment: Above throws an error: `unexpected text ;` from `alert('hello world');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not Jade & jQuery, it's Jade & JavaScript ;)

Jade try to interpret your JavaScript code as Jade code.
You need to write the JavaScript as a plain text.
For you purpose you can use the `block in a tag` syntax, just add a **dot** after `script`:

```
script.
    alert('hello world');
    $("#message").html("message set through jquery")
```

source: [documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/)

---

There is another error at the loop. `each` is Jade syntax and not JavaScript, you could also loop with JavaScript code, but that would look not very nice.
In the next line you try to write plain text/HTML, but it's not plain, see above.

```
if pendingArray
    each item in pendingArray
        h1=val
```

source: [documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)